# xarray dropping elements along a sliced dimension

Tags: python, slice, netcdf, python-xarray

I am reading a NetCDF (time, level, lat, lon) file with xarray. I am selecting two slices over level with the same size.
I am wondering when I am doing an addition of the two files.

The resulting file is not giving the right dimension.

slice1  -> (72, **22**, 41, 36)

slice2  -> (72, **22**, 41, 36)

result  -> (72, **21**, 41, 36)

What is wrong?

Here code that I am using

```
import xarray as xr
fname  =  "DJF_uvwq_lev_monhourly_2017.nc"
ds = xr.open_dataset(fname)
            
u = ds['u']
level   = ds['level']
            
a = u.isel(level=slice(0, len(plev)-1))
b = u.isel(level=slice(1, len(plev)))
            
fluxInterp = a + b
            
print(np.shape(a))
print(np.shape(b))
print(np.shape(fluxInterp))
```

Comment: if you print out ``a['level']``,``b['level']``and ``fluxInterp['level']``, you will see what you did by ``fluxInterp = a + b`` returned the intersection of ``a`` and ``b``.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike numpy, which aligns data based on the position in the array, xarray uses *labels* along a given dimension to align the data when performing data operations. Therefore, having offset labels as in the case of `a` and `b` along the level dimension will not perform the way you're expecting.

Setting up a dummy example:

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr, pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: u = xr.DataArray(np.arange(5), dims=['level'], coords=[list('abcde')])

In [3]: u
Out[3]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 5)>
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
```

When looking at a and b in your example, you're slicing the data using an offset (`slice(0, length-1)` vs `slice(1, length)`). When you do this, notice that the indices of "level" are no longer aligned:

```py
In [4]: a = u.isel(level=slice(0, len(u.level)- 1))
   ...: b = u.isel(level=slice(1, len(u.level)))

In [5]: a
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 4)>
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'

In [6]: b
Out[6]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 4)>
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
```

When adding the two, or in any operation that involves broadcasting & automatic alignment (see the docs references below), missing values will be dropped from the result. Furthermore, in the results, note that the sum is the elementwise-sum where each element is aligned based on the label (b + b, c + c, d + d), not based on position (b + a, c + b, d + c).

```py
In [7]: a + b
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 3)>
array([2, 4, 6])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

What you're looking for is to first use the [`shift`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.shift.html) method to shift the axis labels, so that the coordinate labels are aligned *before* you do the addition:

```py
In [10]: c = u.shift(level=-1)

In [11]: c
Out[11]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 5)>
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'

In [12]: a + c
Out[12]:
<xarray.DataArray (level: 4)>
array([1., 3., 5., 7.])
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

Now, when you add across `a + c` the coordinates line up in the way you'd like.

For more information, see the xarray Computation docs on [broadcasting by dimension name](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name) and [automatic alignment](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment).